# Ethernet drivers for Asus ROG Crosshair VIII Dark Hero

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, asus, amd-ryzen

Cleaned up for clarity

Problem -  Ubuntu won't recognize wired network Using 2.5 gb ethernet port.

Notes - Wifi Works,
Regular Gig port works,
Known Good Cable,
2.5gb port leds light up when cable plugged in,
(also works when on windows 10)

System Setup -

```
Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS
64bit
dual booting with win 10
ryzen 9 5900x
crosshair viii dark hero x570 asus ROG
amd radeon rx 6800xt
gskill trident z royal 64gb (16x4)
galahad aio 360
```

Terminal says -

```
     lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3
    04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [10ec:8125] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller [1043:87d7]
        Kernel modules: r8169
    05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1043:85f0]
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
```

Terminal says with only 2.5 gig plugged in with known good ethernet cable and wifi turned off -

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep igb
[    0.999385] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.6.0-k
[    0.999386] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Intel Corporation.
[    1.030784] igb 0000:05:00.0: added PHC on eth0
[    1.030784] igb 0000:05:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[    1.030785] igb 0000:05:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) fc:34:97:a2:99:d5
[    1.030786] igb 0000:05:00.0: eth0: PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.030787] igb 0000:05:00.0: Using MSI-X interrupts. 2 rx queue(s), 2 tx queue(s)
[    1.031419] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
[  405.260371] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: igb: enp5s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[ 1904.635074] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: igb: enp5s0 NIC Link is Down

$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:34:97:a2:99:d5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d4:64:dc:7f:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Terminal says -

```
$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc80ffff memory:fc810000-fc813fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: fc:34:97:a2:99:d5
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:37 memory:fc700000-fc71ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fc720000-fc723fff
```

Is "unclaimed" the problem?

Terminal says -

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep enp
[    1.031419] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth0
[  405.260371] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: igb: enp5s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
[  405.368054] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp5s0: link becomes ready
[ 1904.635074] igb 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: igb: enp5s0 NIC Link is Down
```

Terminal says -

```
uname -r
5.8.0-55-generic
```

```
$ ls /usr/lib/modules/5.8.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/
8139cp.ko  8139too.ko  atp.ko  r8169.ko
```

```
~$ modinfo r8169 | grep 8125
firmware:       rtl_nic/rtl8125a-3.fw
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008125sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

```
$ sudo modprobe r8169 && sudo dmesg | grep r81
[    0.059668] percpu: Embedded 56 pages/cpu s192512 r8192 d28672 u262144
[    0.059672] pcpu-alloc: s192512 r8192 d28672 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.997443] r8169 0000:04:00.0: unknown chip XID 641
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126269/discussion-on-question-by-ivy-ethernet-drivers-for-asus-rog-crosshair-viii-dark).

Comment: Nice machine :)